# What is a G-Check and what are the differences relative to other checks?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Tried looking for a definition on wikipedia for a G-Check. The wikipage only mentions A,B,C,D checks.

Any ideas what a G-check exactly is? I think I found an article stating it is a 7500 hr major inspection. What is considered a major inspection relative to a minor?

Comment: @SMSvonderTann I'm not sure what to think of forcefully cutting a users question, that seems... wrong. Saying something in the comments is one thing, but removing parts of the question on their behalf? I don't know. I would never do something like this over on SO (where I have enough rep (>20k) to do it).

Comment: Can you give an example of where you saw the term "g-check"? Some context might help

Comment: Could it be an overweight/high-G landing check? Would be done after any overly forceful landing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to tell based on your question, but I think you are talking about an inspection due to an over-G reported on a flight either by the pilot or the flight control system post-flight report.

Maintainers will do inspections of known stress points on the aircraft to look for breaks, cracking or loosened parts and then declare it safe for flight or fix anything out of tolerance.  For a low level over-G, this could be pulling a few panels.  For higher level over-Gs it could be 8 hours worth of work